# virsh list is empty when run from user crontab

Tags: scripts, virtualization, cron

I have added a couple of hypervisors with Ubuntu 18.04 and added the scripts that works on 16.04 and 14.04.

Among them are some scripts that are installed in the user crontab.

Here's part of the script.

```
 virsh list | grep $1
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     log "Start VM: $1"
     virsh start $1
 else
     log "VM already running: $1"
 fi
```

The log's show that virsh list come up empty when run from user crontab. It works from the command line, and from root crontab.

Anyone know how to make it work from user crontab in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

Better to test grep directly.

```bsh
d=${1:?Missing name argument}

if ! virsh -c qemu:///system list | \
         grep -Eq "\ +${d}\ +running$"
then
    log "Start VM: $1"
    virsh start "$1"
else
    log "VM already running: $1"
fi
```

Comment: The problem is that when running "virsh list > some-log-file" from a user crontab the output is empty.

Comment: Running the same command from either root crontab or a terminal - the output is the actual list of running vm's.

Comment: `virsh list --all > some-logfile 2>&1`

Comment: Found the solution:

virsh run from users crontab on ubuntu 18.04 did not connect automatically to local kvm, so the working command was: `virsh -c qemu:///system list`

Comment: nice i put that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I too couldn't get `cron` script to list *any* VMs.

Correct answer as per @johnny-haugen-sørgård in the comments

> Found the solution: virsh run from users crontab on ubuntu 18.04 did not connect automatically to local kvm, so the working command was: virsh -c qemu:///system list

So on the first line of the script, it should be:

```bash
virsh -c qemu:///system list | grep $1
```